# Wifi hardware to improvement network

Tags: wifi, router

I do not know if the question is well located, but I come to request a recommendation, I am having problems with getting a wireless router that meets my needs, in this case I look for one that can manage broadband through QOS or some method of Administration, but that has capacity for about 20 Devices. Now I have a DLINK Dir 822 and every 50 seconds the connection is dropped, I do not know if it's because of the warm atmosphere of the tropic at this time, but I want a new computer to solve this in my house. regards

Comment: So your core requirements are a) support for 20 devices over WiFi and b) that it can cope with tropical conditions. Anything else? Price? Top Speed? Standards?

Comment: C) bandwith control; Price <= 100? Top =anyone? Standards=most common to get compatibilty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to try my luck with a router:
Asus RT-AC51U AC750

And use a pair of access point in the house.

So far, all stable, stable speeds, 0 drops, the router accepts multiple configurations and extensive compatibility .

and Based on Linux.